How to parallelize a for-loop within a defined function using Ray in Python
I have been tasked with parallelizing a piece of code for a huge project I am taking a part in. The code.py I have been tasked with the parallelization goes something like this:
import numpy as np #importing modules sections
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import os
from Auxiliar_py.functions import func1 #import func1 from functions.py within Auxiliar_py folder
... #many lines of code omitted for conciseness

constant1=10 #constant section
constant2=20
loops=fits.open('loops.fits')
loops_list=len(loops)
...

def mainFunction(arg1,arg2,arg3,...): #the main function
    var01=constant1+1
    var02=func1(var01)
    ...
    attempt=0
    max_attempts=5
    for i in tqdm(range(len(loops))):
         while attempt < max_attempts:
                try:

                    for p in range(5):           # <------ the loops I want to parallelize 
                        var11=func1(var01)       # <------ 
                        var12=func1(var11)       # <------ 
                        var13=func2(var01,var12) # <------ 
                        ...                      # <------ this entire sections takes 400+ lines of code
              

                    break  
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
                    attempt += 1
                    print(f"Attempt {attempt} out of {max_attempts}")
    var21=var11+20
    var22=func3(var13)
    ....



To my horror, there are nested loops within the desired function which takes a HUGE toll on the performance.  While I am able to, using Ray, parallelize other sections of the code including some sections within for p in range(5), the entire section of the loop bugs me the most. Is there a way to parallelize that for-loop using Ray without rewriting 400+ lines of code within it?
The solutions I could think of but too scared to attempt are:

Turn all of the functions and processes within the loop into 1 function, decorate it with @ray.remote, and use it here at the loops to enable parellization. This will, however, require me to manually list the inputs and outputs of the 400+ codes so I can define it as a function.

Rewrite everything.


I'm currently new to parallelization so any answers and comments are hugely appreciated. Thank you all in advance.
Note: While other packages/modules for parallelization are avalible, Ray is the most suitable for this project as a whole. It will be greatly appreciated if I can stick to Ray and not change to other packages.

if your function has 400+ lines then maybe it makes too much. Maybe it should be splitted to smaller functions. :) But I would choose your point (1). And I would try to write code which generates list the inputs and outputs :) But problem can be when one loop depends on results from previous loop - because it can't be parallelized

Thank you @furas for the comment! The 400+ lines of code have already included smaller functions and the loop itself does not depend on the results from the previous loop. Would 1) make one big function and parallelize the loop or 2) group sections of the code and parallelize within loop be more efficient?

I think it would be simper to parallelize the loop. Other idea: if you can split file 'loops.fits' into smaller files then you could run current script many times (at the same time) but with different smaller files - and it doesn't need changes in loop. You can use & in system to run script (or other program) in background, and then you can start next script with other small file (also with &), etc. python script.py file1.fits &, python script.py file2.fits &, etc. You can even put all lines in file .bat (on Windows) or .sh (on Linux/MacOS) and run all script at once.
